# How do I arrange this in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not sure how to properly phrase this question, so bear with me while I try and explain.

I am working on a layout that is two columns but with three divs and using the Bootstrap framework. The first div is pushed to the right, the second div is pulled to the left. The third div I want it pulled to the right and set flush to the bottom of the first div. Right now the top of the third div is sitting at the bottom of the second div.

The reason why I want it laid out this way is so when viewing on a desktop there will be two columns but when viewing on a mobile devices it will shrink down to one column and the third div will be below the content in the second div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">DIV1. This will be on the right</div>
    <div class="div2">DIV2. This will be on the left</div>
    <div class="div3">DIV3. This will be on the right</div>
</div>
```

Full CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/m8z37q0y/1/

Comment: please upload a drawing of the result you want to get, it's hard to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `position: relative;` properties *or* add it to the container as well. Then actually use `float: right;` on `div1` and `div3` and remove the right/left properties:

```
    .container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 250px;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .div1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #eee;
        float: right;
    }
    .div2 {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #aaa;
        float: left;
    }
    .div3 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #777;
        float: right;
    }
```

See the ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8z37q0y/9/)***

Comment: I took a look at the demo and it is perfect. I will have to check tomorrow to make sure I can get it to work with bootstrap but I do not think that will be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/m8z37q0y/7/

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:green ;
    left: 300px;
    float: right;

}
.div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    right: 100px;
    float: left;

}

.div3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;

    float: right;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### View <kbd>[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8z37q0y/3/)</kbd>

Remove **`position: relative`**  property in **`.div2{...}`** and **`.div3 {...}`** class.

Change property value **`float: left`**  to  **`float: right`**  in **`.div3{...}`** class to archive this.

```
.div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
    right: 100px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;      /* Remove this */
}
.div3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #777;
    left: 300px;
    float: left;             /* Set float Right */
    position: relative;      /* Remove this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/m8z37q0y/8/
You should remove the all css property below:
`position: relative; left...`
and set correct `float` property like below:

```
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    float: right;
}
.div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
    float: left;
}
.div3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #777;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container">

<div class="div1">DIV1. This will be on the right</div>
    <div class="div2">DIV2. This will be on the left</div>

    <div class="div3">DIV3. This will be on the right</div>
</div>


         .container {
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
background: #ccc;
     }
.div1 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #eee;
left: 300px;
float:right;
}
.div2 {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: #aaa;
right: 100px;
float:left;

 }
 .div3 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #777;
left: 300px;
float:right;

}
```